# ¿Mostrar mensaje "No hay resultados" en un pipe filter de Angular con typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

input html de la busqueda

```
<input class="form-control" name="filterTarea" placeholder="Buscar" [(ngModel)]="filterTarea">
```

recorrido que trae los datos desde mysql

```
<div class="col-lg-4" *ngFor="let emp of tarea | filter:filterTarea | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 6, currentPage: p};">
```

pipe del filtro despues del if tal vez se podria poner un else

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "filter",
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, arg: any): any {
    const restarea = [];
    for (const tarea of value) {
      if (tarea.Nombre_Empresa.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        restarea.push(tarea);
      }
    }
    return restarea;
  }
}
```

Comment: Porfavor explica mejor el resultado que esperas. No es claro que lo que quieres hacer

Comment: `transform(value: any, arg: any): any` >>> el poder de TypeScript está en manejar los tipos...

Comment: @ajuni880 el filtro funciona correctamente mi duda es: al escribir en el buscador algo que no coincidacon naday no arroje resultados.. imprimir un mensaje "no se encontraron resultados"

Comment: @samuelsantos En tu caso, no veo una solución factible porque el filtro lo aplicas a un array y si devuelves un string la directiva `ngFor` va a dar error porque espera un iterable. Aun que se podría añadir(cuando no hay coincidencias) en el array el mensaje de error algo asi `[{error: 'mi error'}]` pero esto tampoco sirve porque luego tienes el filtro de paginación y se podría producir un comportamiento inesperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo pude resolver y fu de la siguiente forma

```
     <ng-container *ngIf="( tarea | filter:filterTarea) as result">

 <div id="contenedor" class="col-12 col-md-4 px-4 py-3" *ngFor="let emp of result | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 6, currentPage: p};">

 <h1 class="text-center mx-auto" style="color: red;" *ngIf="result.length === 0">no se encontraron resultados</h1>
     </ng-container>
```

Comment: Es recomendable explicar lo que realiza el código? revisar [answer], saludos.